# Dynamic, application-wide replacement of a WCF client endpoint

Tags: wcf, silverlight

We are developing a Silverlight application where we use a third party component that calls a WCF web service. Unfortunately, this component does not let us specify the endpoint configuration name; instead, it uses a hardcoded endpoint name, say, `TheEndpoint`. This is problematic because we need to be able to choose between different endpoint configurations based on some conditions that are detected by the C# code. I assume that WCF maintains some kind of repository of those endpoints that are defined in App.config, since they can be used whenever you create a new client channel - is it possible to insert new endpoints into this repository? I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
bool useSSL = ...;
var mode = useSSL ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport : BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(mode) {Name = "TheEndpoint"};
var address = (useSSL ? "https" : "http") + "://example.com/service.svc";
MagicalWcfEndpointRepository.AddClientEndpoint(
    typeof(ITheInterface), binding, address);
```

Whenever I google for this, I find plenty of tips on how to dynamically create endpoints, but they all assume that you create the client channel yourself. This is not the case here; the component has its own client proxy that it instantiates directly, and there is no way for us to inject another channel or channel factory. Also, I know that it is possible to use a config transform to change the contents of App.config, but that would cause each individual installation of the application to be tied to one specific endpoint. We would like each application to be able to choose between different endpoints at startup time. Is this possible?

Comment: There is no magical WCF repository. WCF pulls data directly from ConfigurationManager. You can add or update an endpoint definition in app.config via ConfigurationManager, but you'll have to write changes back to file (and potentially Refresh) which you explicitly said you don't want to do. Perhaps you should re-tag and edit this question to be ConfigurationManager based.

Comment: @ErnieL That's what I was afraid of. :-( Given that this is a Silverlight application, I suppose that it is impossible to write the changes back anyway, since the config comes from a XAP package that is downloaded from the server.